# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. (RestSharp, SSL Client Certificates)

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate, restsharp

I have following code which is calling an API using basic authentication and SSL client certificate but its throwing exception and giving me following error.

**"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."**

I tried to find a solution on Google but failed to find any solution. Can anyone help me out on this. Thanks.

```
// Variables 

string basicAuthenticationUserName = "username";
string basicAuthenticationPassword = "password";
string clientCertificateFilePath = "Path-To-Certificate-File";
string clientCertificatePassword = "certificate-password";
string url = "https://" + basicAuthenticationUserName + ":" + basicAuthenticationPassword + "@apiserverurl/apimethod";

// Creating RestSharp Request Object 

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
    OnBeforeDeserialization = resp =>
    {
        resp.ContentType = "application/json";
    }
};

// Adding Headers

request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "0");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/x-null-message");

// Importing Certificates

var certificates = new X509Certificate();
certificates.Import(clientCertificateFilePath, clientCertificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

// Creating RestSharp Client Object

var client = new RestClient
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri(url),
    ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection { certificates },
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(managingLou, basicAuthenticationPassword)
};

// Executing Request 

var response = client.Execute<T>(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue. Let me mention the steps here for your help.

After the installation of windows service, I went through the following steps to fix the issue:

- Go To Start > Run and type Services.msc
- Select your service > Right click and choose Properties
- Select the 2nd tab "Log On"
- Select the radio button "This account"
- Enter the username and password of currently log in user. (Make sure Its the same user who has installed the service)
- Apply the changes
- Start the service

Comment: What service are you referring to?